# Use network location instead of local drive

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, .net-3.5

I have the following which works fine:

```
Function DirSearch(ByVal sDir As String) As String
    For Each d As String In Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)
        For Each f As String In Directory.GetFiles(d)
            objSQLStringBuilder.Append("insert into table1 (full_path, file_name) values ('" & "file:///" + f.Replace("'", "''").Replace(" ", "%20").Replace("\", "/") & "', '" & f.Remove(0, Len(d) + 1).Replace("'", "''") & "');")
        Next
        DirSearch(d)
    Next

    Return objSQLStringBuilder.ToString
End Function
```

How would I go about changing this to work with UNC's instead of local directory mappings?

For example, at the moment if I set `sDir` to `C:\`, the code works fine.  What changed do I need to make so it works with something `\\server\c$\` instead?

Comment: What _does_ it currently do when you call `DirSearch()` with an UNC path?

Comment: Works fine for me - are you sure you have permissions to look at the directories and files? Try the same UNC in Windows Explorer. BTW you are going to get a zillion lines back if you go for the root. I assume you are narrowing the search a bit. Might make more sense to create CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so you know to return the `path` of `shared folder`

```
dim myLocalpath as string = "c:\"
dim mysharedpath as string = "\\"  & Environment.MachineName & "\" & myLocalpath
Consloe.Writeline(mysharedpath) 

Output: 

\\server\c:\
```

Comment: @JohnDoyle this sounds like critique ? it is really an answer highlight me the critique or your clarification ...